# Inputting an ARRAY into a FORM field in REACT

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn to code by following an eCommerce product tutorial guide in React.
I have finished setting up the product page and checkout.

My goal now is to extract the cart: [] along with the checkout total into a form using EmailJS.

```
import React from 'react';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import './form.css';
import { ProductConsumer } from '../../context'
import CartList from './CartList'
import CartColumns from "./CartColumns"
import CartTotals from './CartTotals'
import Title from "../Title";
import { ProductProvider } from "../../context"
import CartItem from './CartItem'


export default function CheckOut() {

  function sendEmail(e) {
    alert("Your order has been placed!")
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'template_3DAGPnwJ', e.target, 'user_m49ol85bvoqFluF8IKatG')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  }


let Order = "cat"

  return (
    <div>
    <ProductConsumer>
      {value => {
        return(
          <div>
          <Title name="Check" title="Out"/>
          <CartColumns />
          <CartList value={value} />
          <CartTotals value={value}/>
              </div>

        )
      }
    }
      </ProductConsumer>
      <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <label>Contact Number eg. 12345678 </label>
        <input type="tel" name="contact_number" placeholder="12345678" pattern="[0-9]{8}" required />
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="user_name" required />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" required />
        <label>Address Line 1</label>
        <input type="address-line1" name="user_address1" required />
        <label>Address Line 2</label>
        <input type="address-line2" name="user_address2" />
        <label>Message (eg. Special Requests)</label>
        <textarea name="message_html" />
        <input type="submit" value="Place Order" />
        <textarea name="proudct order" value={Order}/>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

So far the textarea is showing "cat" from the **let Order =  "cat".**
I would like to put the array information from **CartList** and **CartTotal** into Order. Once the client submits the form, I will have their name email address and the order they collected in the cart. This will be emailed to me via EmailJS.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import './form.css';
import { ProductConsumer } from '../../context';
import CartList from './CartList';
import CartTotals from './CartTotals';
import Title from '../Title';



export default function CheckOut() {
  function sendEmail(e) {
    alert('Your order has been placed! Our staff will get in touch with you to confirm your order and to process payment.');
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        'gmail',
        'xxxxxxxxx',
        e.target,
        'xxxxxxxxx'
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  }

  const Form = ({ context }) => {
    let Order = context.cart.map((item) => `ID: ${item.id} \n${item.title} \t $ ${item.price} \t Qty:${item.count} \n\n`);
    let OrderSubtotal = context.cartSubtotal ;
    let OrderServce = context.cartService;
    let OrderShipping = context.cartShipping;
    let OrderTotal = context.cartTotal;

    return (
      <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <label>Contact Number eg. 12345678 </label>
        <input
          type="tel"
          name="contact_number"
          placeholder="12345678"
          pattern="[0-9]{8}"
          required
        />
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="user_name" required />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" required />
        <label>Address Line 1</label>
        <input type="address-line1" name="user_address1" required />
        <label>Address Line 2</label>
        <input type="address-line2" name="user_address2" />
        <label>Message (eg. Special Requests)</label>
        <textarea name="message_html" />
        <input type="submit" value="Place Order" />
        <textarea style={{display:"none"}} name="Order" defaultValue={Order} />
        <textarea style={{display:"none"}} name="OrderSubtotal" defaultValue={OrderSubtotal} />
        <textarea style={{display:"none"}} name="OrderServce" defaultValue={OrderServce} />
        <textarea style={{display:"none"}} name="OrderShipping" defaultValue={OrderShipping} />
        <textarea style={{display:"none"}} name="OrderTotal" defaultValue={OrderTotal} />


      </form>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
    <ProductConsumer>
      {(value) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Title name="Check" title="Out" />
            <CartList value={value} />
            <CartTotals value={value} />
            </div>


        );
      }}
      </ProductConsumer>
      <ProductConsumer>
        {(context) => <Form context={context} />}
      </ProductConsumer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The answer.

import { ProductConsumer } from '../../context';

let Order = context.cart.map((item) => `ID: ${item.id} \n${item.title} \t $ ${item.price} \t Qty:${item.count} \n\n`);

which is then exported to emailJS in the textarea.

```
 <textarea style={{display:"none"}} name="Order" defaultValue={Order} />
```

and rendered

```
  <ProductConsumer>
    {(context) => <Form context={context} />}
  </ProductConsumer>
```

Answer suggested by Metafield on Scrimba Discord Community. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can and should use `state` to update any variable in a React component! `CheckOut` is a functional component. To use state in a functional component you have to use a hook, which is `useState`.

To get value from `CartList` and `CartTotal` and update `Order`, pass callback functions from `CheckOut` component.

Please check the following code, hope it helps.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import "./form.css";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../../context";
import CartList from "./CartList";
import CartColumns from "./CartColumns";
import CartTotals from "./CartTotals";
import Title from "../Title";
import { ProductProvider } from "../../context";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";

export default function CheckOut() {
  // Order default value is empty array. i.e. no orders
  // updateOrder will update Order
  const [Order, updateOrder] = useState([]);

  // cartTotal to store CartTotals value
  // updateCartTotal will update cartTotal
  const [cartTotal, updateCartTotal] = useState(0);

  function sendEmail(e) {
    alert("Your order has been placed!");
    e.preventDefault();

    // You can access Order and cartTotal here.
    console.log(Order, cartTotal);

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "gmail",
        "template_3DAGPnwJ",
        e.target,
        "user_m49ol85bvoqFluF8IKatG"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ProductConsumer>
        {(value) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Title name="Check" title="Out" />
              <CartColumns />
              {/* updateOrder is a callback passed by prop */}
              <CartList value={value} onCartUpdate={updateOrder} />
              {/* updateCartTotal is a callback passed by prop */}
              <CartTotals value={value} onCartTotalUpdate={updateCartTotal} />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </ProductConsumer>
      <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <label>Contact Number eg. 12345678 </label>
        <input
          type="tel"
          name="contact_number"
          placeholder="12345678"
          pattern="[0-9]{8}"
          required
        />
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="user_name" required />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" required />
        <label>Address Line 1</label>
        <input type="address-line1" name="user_address1" required />
        <label>Address Line 2</label>
        <input type="address-line2" name="user_address2" />
        <label>Message (eg. Special Requests)</label>
        <textarea name="message_html" />
        <input type="submit" value="Place Order" />
        <textarea name="proudct order" value={Order} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I see your input fields are uncontrolled! React suggests to use a controlled component for form input. You can get idea from here - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Also, since you are learning React I suggest you read about two core parts of React. They are `props` and `state`.

For working with forms you can check this popular form handling library for react. https://formik.org/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I will try to get it to work and report back!

Comment: I've tried the code. Initially, had to change useState to React.useState because the compiler said useState was not defined. Not sure if useState == React.useState. With no errors, i put the console log under the email funciton, and when submitting the form, it produces two empty arrays. I will continue trying. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! You have to call the `onCartUpdate` and `onCartTotalUpdate` callbacks from your `CartList` and `CartTotals` component respectively. Otherwise it will always be empty array and zero. 

More precisely, On the `CartList` component call  `onCartUpdate` when any product add or remove from the cart.